# FormControlName dentro de um NgFor

Tags: angular

Eu tenho um ngFor com campos gerados dinamicamente através da adição de linhas ou colunas.

porém se o usuário resolver colocar mais de uma coluna ou linha, o value do form virá apenas com o ultimo valor que o usuário digitou.

Como eu conseguiria pegar todos os dados de todos os inputs?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="header-content">
      <p>Infome os dados</p>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-content">
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <table>
          <tr class="add-and-remove">
            <th></th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" (click)="removeColum()"></i></th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-plus" (click)="addColum()"></i></th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="form-of">
            <td>
              <div class="select-wrapper">
                <select>
                  <option value="maximizar">Maximizar</option>
                  <option value="minimizar">Minimizar</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="variable-input" *ngFor="let num of colums">
              <div class="colums">
                <input type="text" placeholder="?" formControlName="functionVar">
                <p>X{{ num }}</p>
                <i class="fa fa-plus" *ngIf="numberOfColums > 1"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="form-st" *ngFor="let numLines of lines; first as isFirst">
            <td>
              <p *ngIf="isFirst">Sujeito à:</p>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let num of colums">
              <div class="colums">
                <input type="text" placeholder="?" formControlName="decisionsVar">
                <p>X{{ num }}</p>
                <i class="fa fa-plus" *ngIf="numberOfColums  > 1"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select>
                <option value="equals0"> ==0 </option>
                <option value="greater0"> >=0 </option>
                <option value="less0"> <= </option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="colums">
                <input type="text" placeholder="?" formControlName="restrictionsVar">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-times" (click)="removeLine()"></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td *ngFor="let num of colums">
              <div>
                <select>
                  <option value="maximizar"> >=0 </option>
                  <option value="minimizar"> <=0 </option>
                  <option value="minimizar"> livre </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-plus" (click)="addLine()"></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="transformBtn">
      <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(form)">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  numberOfColums: number = 1;
  numberOfLines: number = 1;
  colums: any;
  lines: any;
  arr:any

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createTableaux()

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      functionVar: ['', Validators.required],
      decisionsVar: ['', Validators.required],
      restrictionsVar: ['', Validators.required]
    })

  }
  
 
  onSubmit(form){
    console.log(form)
  }
  createTableaux(){
    this.colums = Array(this.numberOfColums)
    this.colums = this.colums.fill().map((x,i)=> i == 0 ? 1 : i + 1);
    this.lines = Array(this.numberOfLines)
    this.lines = this.lines.fill().map((x,i)=> i == 0 ? 1 : i + 1);
  }
  addColum(){
    this.numberOfColums++
    this.createTableaux()
  }
  removeColum(){
    if(this.numberOfColums > 1){
      this.numberOfColums--
      this.createTableaux()
    }
    this.createTableaux()
  }
  addLine(){
    this.numberOfLines++
    this.createTableaux()
  }
  removeLine(){
    if(!(this.numberOfLines <= 1)){
      this.numberOfLines--
      this.createTableaux()   
    }
    this.createTableaux()
  }
}
```

Comment: voce tem que usar formArray

Comment: @EduardoVargas de que forma?